# 2003 chchevorlet S-10 pickup truck

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, s10

My abs light comes on but then it goes away my problem is when im coming to a complete stop you hear a noise a little motor sound and then the left side driver side like it pulls to the right side it does it repeatedly when im coming to a complete stop. On the same side.I change front pads still the sameand then i had some fluid on the drive way.maybe it's not getting fluid in the right side i seen some fluid uder the plastic container that holds the brake fluid like a aluminum peace holding plastic container,maybe master cylinder please help with your opinions.

Comment: You really need to get the codes read, but you cannot do this with just any OBDII reader, you need one which will do the ABS (and most which have that also do SRS). It should tell you whats going on.

Comment: Sounds like a wheel speed sensor, but get the code read first to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to jack it up and check the brakes and look to see if the fluid is coming from the brakes. It would be on the tire or the wheel on the inside.  Look it over and try to pinpoint the origin of the fluid leak first. While it is up, check for any looseness by moving the tire left - right and up-down. You could have a bad caliper, bad wheel bearing or something broken.